# JNI functions in Android webkit source

Tags: android, webview, webkit, java-native-interface

I [read that](http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial#Naming_Functions) JNI functions (the native C part) is very complex and must contain the java package name.

However, when reading Android webkit source. For example the `nativeMoveGeneration` functions in [WebView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java)

```
private native int      nativeMoveGeneration();
```

It calls the JNI functions in [WebView.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_external_webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit/android/nav/WebView.cpp)

```
static int nativeMoveGeneration(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    WebView* view = GET_NATIVE_VIEW(env, obj);
    if (!view)
        return 0;
    return view->moveGeneration();
}
```

Ihis JNI function does not follow naming rule. Why is it?

P/S: The function above is just for demonstration. I'm reading Android 4.0.3 source, so it may be different from the github source above

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Alex Cohn and this [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html), I know that we can use JNI_Onload or use complex name. But where should we put JNI_Onload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI defines special function, **JNI_OnLoad**. It is called before any JNI method is called, and it can populate the table of native methods using pointers to any C functions. See [the official document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html)

Comment: I read all samples in Android NDK package, but see no JNI_OnLoad, is it arbitrary? Is there any difference between C or C++ source?

Comment: You are right, people prefer the default binding as provided by **javah** tool. There are very few cases when use of **JNI_OnLoad** is justified. Mainly it helps to perform initialization of global objects. Performing it on load you are often less worried about multithreading race conditions or about immediate response to user actions. Regarding populating the table of native methods in **JNI_OnLoad**, there may be some performance gain for extremely long tables, and WebKit does have a lot of native methods to map.

Comment: Another good reason for not using JNI discovery is that now the methods can be declared "static" so the names don't take up space in the symbol table on the device.